# True or false? If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to $y^{\prime\prime} + x^2y = 1$, then $y_1 + y_2$ is also a solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove if this is true or false:
>   If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the differential equation 
>   $$y^{\prime\prime} + x^2y = 1$$ 
>   then $y_1 + y_2$ is also a solution to this equation.

How do I show if this is true or not? Please help me! :)

Comment: Do you know what a linear differential equation is and what the elementary consequences of "linear" for the solution space are?

Comment: No i dont really know

Comment: Is it true or not this question?

Comment: While $y_1+y_2$ is not a solution, $ty_1+(1-t)y_2$ is a solution for any $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y_1, y_2$ are solutions of $y^{\prime\prime} + x^2y = 1$

$\implies y_1^{\prime\prime} + x^2y_1 = 1, y_2^{\prime\prime} + x^2y_2 = 1$

Now, keep $y=y_1+y_2$,

$\implies (y_1+y_2)''+x^2(y_1+y_2)=[y_1^{\prime\prime} + x^2y_1]+[y_2^{\prime\prime} + x^2y_2]=1+1=2\neq1$.

So, $y_1+y_2$ is not a solution of the given differential equation.